# Remove records, where 2 columns could include records with id from same set

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.1

Given the table with columns

```
| user_id | owner_id | something |
```

I need to remove all records, where **user_id OR owner_id** exist in another table

like:

```
delete from permission 
  where 
    user-id in (select user_id from users where  a = 2) 
      or 
        owner_id in (select user_id from users where a = 2)
```

how should I do that without invoking same queries twice?

Comment: What is the problem with your query?  If you have indexes set up for it, then it will run quite fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `USING` clause:

```
DELETE FROM permissions
USING users
WHERE users.user_id IN (permissions.user_id, permissions.owner_id)
/*
or:
WHERE (permissions.user_id = users.user_id OR permissions.owner_id = users.user_id)
*/
  AND users.a = 2
;
```

Reference:

- [DELETE (PostgreSQL Documentation)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-delete.html)

Note: this syntax is not standard, as duly specified in the manual.

Answer (score 0):

You could use join to find rows in permissions that satisfy your criteria:

```
delete from permissions
  where (user_id, owner_id) in
      (select p.user_id, p.owner_id 
       from permissions p 
            join users on (u.user_id = p.user_id or u.user_id = p.owner_id))
```

Provided that you have indices on user_id and owner_id it would boil down to a couple of joined index scans.

Comment: permission doesn't have id, and join would be overkill I guess

Comment: Edited so that id in permissions is not necessary. Also, join is never overkill unless planner tells you so. Do you actually see a horrible execution plan? What is in there?